# I tried to install minecraft on my chromebook via linux and it says: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64) how can i fix that?

Tags: java, 64-bit, minecraft, chromebook

I tried to install minecraft on my chromebook via linux and it says:  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64) how can i fix that ?

Comment: You are trying to put a left shoe onto a right foot. You "fix" it by using the correct shoe for the foot, by using the correct build for the CPU architecture. You need arm64 software for an arm64 CPU.

Comment: Need to try something like this: https://nicholasbering.ca/raspberry-pi/2020/10/18/minecraft-64bit-rpi4/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Minecraft Launcher is built for another CPU type than the one in your Chromebook. The game itself is compatible with ARM CPUs as far as I know. To get around this problem you could try to use [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/), an alternative Launcher for the game which should support your CPU.